# Why an empty array in javascript entering for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following code snippet:

```
console.log('**1**',parentNode.child.length); //1
            for(var ch in parentNode.child)
            {
                console.log('PTree root child',parentNode.child[ch]); //2
            }
```

In //1 parentNode.child.length comes out to be 0
but still it goes inside the for loop and gives following output in line //2:

```
PTree root child (val) {
        if (this.indexOf(val) === -1) {
            this.push(val);
        }

        return this;
    }
```

I am not sure why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I assume parentNode.child is array. 
So, here are the possibilities which could cause this.

1. That array has a non-numeric named property.

```js
var data = [];
data.someFunc = function(){};
console.log("length: %s", data.length);
for(var key in data) console.log("%s: %s",key, data[key]);
```

2. You monkey-patched Array.prototype somehow.

```js
Array.prototype.coolFunc = function(){ return "cool" };
var data = [];
console.log("length: %s", data.length);
for(var key in data) console.log("%s: %s", key, data[key]);
```

So, to avoid this simply use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var data = [];
data.someFunc = function(){};
console.log("length: %s", data.length);
data.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```